# What game is this as seen in Charlie and the Chocolate Factory (2005)?

Tags: game-identification

If you look at [this video](https://youtu.be/zslNn8Cd0-A?t=3m30s) around the 3:30 mark, one of the "Golden Ticket" winners in the movie is this kid.  A bunch of news anchors are over his house to interview him about his win, but he is too focused on playing this game:

[image: Game Picture]

The picture above can be viewed around the [3:55 mark](https://youtu.be/zslNn8Cd0-A?t=3m55s).  The movie shows about 2 seconds of gameplay at that point.  What is the name of this game?

If it helps at all, here is the console he is playing it on as seen in the movie:

[image: pictute of Console]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that the game Mike is playing in this sequence doesn't really exist. It is simply a game created specifically for this movie. As stated on this [site](http://www.moviemistakes.com/film5145/questions):

> Question: What video game was Mike Teevee playing and what system is it for?
>
> Answer: It's not a real game - the sequence was created specifically for the film by a company called Digi-Guys based in Ealing Studios in the UK. The software used was Softimage XSI and Digital Fusion.

Comment: Bah! Leave it to the movies to not even have the dignity to use a real video game...

Comment: @TimmyJim Guess it's just generally cheaper to do a mockup than buying the rights to use a real game for merely 2 seconds... It's quite a standard practice to use mock software in such scenes AFAIK.