# What game is Yu Ishigami playing in Kaguya-sama: Love Is War Final (the 2021 sequel)?

Tags: game-identification

Update: In a better quality version, we can see something called 'AK-12 Rebellion'.

[image]

---

What game is Yu Ishigami playing in *Kaguya-sama: Love Is War Final* ([2021](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaguya-sama_Final:_Love_Is_War) sequel to the [2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaguya-sama:_Love_Is_War_(film)) adaptation of *[Kaguya-sama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaguya-sama:_Love_Is_War)*)?

Note: This is really in the 2021 live movie rather than in the [2021 mini live movies](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Kaguya-sama_wa_Kokurasetai_Live_Action_Mini).

[image: screenshot]

Looks like some FPS. If I didn't know better, then I'd say it's CS:GO, specifically Mirage when you come out of underpass and then Yu is using an SG (Krieg) or something.

[Here's the GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGkP6.jpg):

[image]

Comment: It could be the Chinese [*Counter-Strike: Global Offensive Perfect World Edition*](https://counterstrike.fandom.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Perfect_World_Edition)

Comment: The image on the monitor seems to loop, so I think the actor/character is not actually playing anything. (Shall I post that as an answer? :)

Comment: @Joachim Lol good observation, but what is the game?

Comment: @BCLC what Joachim means is that they aren't playing a real game, and therfore it can't be identified. This is actually quite common in films/shows. We've had a few game identification questions that result in this answer.

Comment: @TimmyJim So where does the footage come from? It's made specifically for the movie instead of taken from an actual game? Wow really? I cannot imagine they would spend so much time to make this instead of just filming Yu to play csgo or valorant or whatever.

Comment: @Joachim wait 'The image on the monitor seems to loop' does it? Looks like strafing or something...

Comment: @BCLC maybe not for this particular scenario, but [it's been done before](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/289777/what-game-is-this-as-seen-in-charlie-and-the-chocolate-factory-2005)

Comment: @TimmyJim ok fine thanks, but I think that has a higher budget than Kaguya-sama 2.

Comment: Very much doubt it's CSGO. Weapon viewmodel and animations don't really look like something out of CSGO, and I don't agree about the weapon looking like the SG (looks more like a modern AK rifle, like a AK-12). Map doesn't really look like Mirage either (and it's definitely not mid, since 1. left wall is too high 2. wall in front (which would be upper mid) has a hole 3. no visible incline/ramp and 4. right wall doesn't seem to have a hole (connector)). UI also doesn't match. I can still see this being a CS game, though. Wasn't there, like, 3 or 4 Asia-exclusive CS games?

Comment: @LeoS. thanks. Stevoisiak said earlier 'Chinese Counter-Strike: Global Offensive Perfect World Edition' what do you think?

Comment: @BCLC That game is basically the same game as the CSGO we have, save for censorship to some textures and effects (no more skulls, no more hammer-and-cickles, no more red blood, no more Italian flags(?), etc) and (non-censorship related) alterations to comply with China's laws. I actually went looking for videos to see if there were other changes not mentioned in the CS wiki (like, major UI changes (changing the mini-map from rounded to squared), new weapons, etc), but could find nothing. So, I find it unlikely to be CSGO:PWE.

Comment: @LeoS. Thanks! post as partial answer? Perhaps you could include some youtube video links to explain why it's unlikely to be the perfect world CSGO?

Comment: I think the "better quality screenshot" section would work better in your answer, rather than the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking up AK-12 Rebellion, this looks like something called [Alliance of Valiant Arms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliance_of_Valiant_Arms) aka 'AVA'. There's a video [AVA - Cursed AK-12 Rebellion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ch2_7q8xTdw), where we seem to see the same kind of gun that Yu uses.

Comment: UI elements appear to also match that game.